# Checking a variable for characters, changing it if they exist

Tags: php

I have this code that is ment to stop people entering dots and slashes into query strings. 
The string is defined to a variable, then if the variable containes a '.' or a '/' i would like to replace them with forbidden and main.

```
    <?php
    if( strpos( $page, '/' ) === true ) { $page = 'forbidden'; $inner_page = 'main'; }
    elseif( strpos( $page, '.' ) === true ) { $page = 'forbidden'; $inner_page = 'main'; }
    elseif( strpos( $inner_page, '/' ) === true ) { $page = 'forbidden'; $inner_page = 'main'; }
    elseif( strpos( $inner_page, '.' ) === true ) { $page = 'forbidden'; $inner_page = 'main'; }
?>
```

This code (isAllowedURL.php) is being loaded into this code:

```
    <?php
    $page = 'home';
    $inner_page = 'main';
if( isset( $_GET['page'] ) )
{
    $page = htmlspecialchars( $_GET['page'] );
}

if( isset( $_GET['subpage'] ) )
{
    $inner_page = htmlspecialchars( $_GET['subpage'] );
}
include ('/indexBuilder/linkSecurity/isAllowedURL.php');
?>
```

As you can see, it changes the variables to the query if it exists and i would like to change it back if the variable containes the banned characters.

Why does this code not function as wanted?

-I changed the true to false and every page was made forbidden, changed it back and none where.

Comment: Check the manual, `strpos()` returns `false` or an integer, never `true`.

Comment: @jeroen This method was suggested by another user. So i should check for != false?

Comment: `!== false` to be exact as `0` - the first position in the array - also evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

You need to use !== to see if they are present. Also you cannot use true with strpos.

```
if( strpos( $page, '/' ) !== false ) { $page = 'forbidden'; $inner_page = 'main'; }
```